# function which returns values that have last 2 numbers greater than a certain value for INT datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-function

Is there any SQL function that I can use to return all those records that have last 2 numbers greater than 31.
Basically, there is one column: OpenDate in INT datatype stored as '19810281' and the last 2 values are 81(which should be a date) so it has erroneous data.

I want to query all those bad records which have last 2 numbers of column: OpenDate as greater than 31?
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Modulo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) function.

```
SELECT OpenDate 
FROM Table
WHERE OpenDate % 100 > 31
```

As you are on 2008 you can use the DATE datatype. This is one byte smaller than an int and will prevent this type of issue.

Or alternatively a more robust check would be to cast the value to char and use `isdate` as `yyyymmdd` is unambiguous.

```
SELECT OpenDate
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  LEN(OpenDate) <> 8
        OR ISDATE(CAST(OpenDate AS CHAR(8))) = 0
```

Comment: I guess the check should be more complex, because February could have 28 or 29 days. Maybe some check including casting the value to a date. It is a pity that we cannot use `TRY_CONVERT`.

Comment: @gotqn - True I just answered the question as asked. Will extend.